# How to add custom templates to bitnami helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm deploying a spring cloud data flow cluster on kubernetes with helm and the [chart from bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow). This works fine.

Now I need an additional template to add a route. Is there a way to somehow add this or inherit from the bitnami chart and extend it? Of course I'd like to reuse all of the variables which are already defined for the spring cloud data flow deployment.

Answer (score 5):

That chart has a specific extension point for doing things like this.  The list of "Common parameters" in the linked documentation includes a line

> **Name:** `extraDeploy`; **Description**: Array of extra objects to deploy with the release; **Value**: `[]`

The implementation calls through to a [helper](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/common/templates/_tplvalues.tpl) in the [Bitnami Common Library Chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/common) that calls the Helm `tpl` function on the value, serializing it to YAML first if it's not a string, so you can use Helm templating within that value.

So specifically for the Bitnami charts, you can include an extra object in your `values.yaml` file:

```yaml
extraDeploy:
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: '{{ include "common.names.fullname" . }}'
    ...
```

As a specific syntactic note, the value of `extraDeploy` is a list of either strings or dictionaries, but any templating is rendered *after* the YAML is parsed; this is different from the normal Helm template flow.  In the example above I've included a YAML object, but then quoted a string value that begins with a `{{ ... }}` template, lest it otherwise be parsed as a YAML mapping.  You could also force the whole thing to be a string, though it might be harder to work with in an IDE.

```yaml
extraDeploy:
  - |-
      metadata:
        name: {{ include "common.names.fullname" . }}
```

Comment: very helpful. Additionally: I used that within a tekton-task, which I also install via helm. There I had to use "{{\`" to force helm to not to evaluate the template in the first pass, e.g.       
`script: |-
        echo "creating my-values.yaml for gitea release"
        cat <<-EOT >> my-values.yaml
        {{\`global:
          imageRegistry: docker.io
.......
                name: {{ include "gitea.fullname" . }}-http\`}}
        EOT
`
here you can find more details: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2798

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the `YAML template file` in the **templates** folder and it will get deployed with the chart.

You can also edit the existing YAML template accordingly and extend it no need to inherit or much things.

For example, if you are looking forward to adding the **ingress** into your chart, add ingress template and respective values block in **values.yaml** file

You can add this whole YAML template in folder : https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/ghost/templates/ingress.yaml

and specific **values.yaml** block for **ingress**.

Or for example your chart dont have any deployment and you want to add deployment you can write your own template or use form internet.

Deployment : https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/ghost/templates

there is `deployment.yaml` file template and you can get specific variables that the template uses into `values.yaml` and you have extended the chart successfully.

Comment: Yes of course. But I don't want to copy and change the bitnami repo. I want to reuse it and just add an additional custom template.

Comment: which helm version you are using ? helm 3 or helm 2 ?

Comment: I'm using helm 3.

Comment: you can use the library chart? did you checked about it ? `{{- include "mylibchart.configmap" (list . "mychart.configmap") -}}`

Comment: here whole reference doc and example : https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/

Comment: or else you can add the chart dependency.

Comment: All of this means, that I have to change/extend the bintmai chart in the first place. I see the bitnami charts as libraries that I use, configure or extend. I don't want to change them.